# SQL : Restrict view of tables in database

Tags: database, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-management-studio

This is probably a no but, I want to be sure. A client wants to connect to SQL Server 2008 that we host. They will be accessing a table to execute an SSIS package to copy some data they have on their database to our database. I am worried about security. Now, I've read certain posts on how to restrict a user to see only one database . I however, want to ask if that can be done for tables inside the database. Meaning can you set it so that the user can only see the tables they need to work with in management studio?

Comment: I'm not sure on that, but maybe you could create a database that holds a copy of those specific tables, and only grant permission to that database.

Comment: You can create a new user and assign him the needed permissions for this client.

Comment: Are you truly meaning **"Set it so that the user can only see the tables they need to work with in SSMS"** or do you mean to **only allow them to SELECT data from the tables they have access regardless of the database name being listed in the SSMS GUI**. Seeing tables as in the table names in SSMS and not being able to select data from those tables could be two different things so I just want to be sure it's clear what you're asking just in case.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, like this:

```
GRANT [Permission] ON [SchemaName].[TableName] to [UserName]
```

Where `[Permission]` is `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `INSERT`. You can also use `DENY` instead of `GRANT` to take permissions away.

**Further reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx**

Answer (score 2):

In addition to imtheman's answer which is good, you can also do a **create view** command which only allows them to interact with the columns you wish them to see.  All other column are not even present.

See this microsoft msdn article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx